# "AAPT2" ERROR 2018

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

I have a problem with Android with the error

"AAPT2 error: check the records for details"

I've seen tutorials and many recommend that you put android.enableAapt2 = false in the gradle.properties file, but I get another error

"The option 'android.enableAapt2' is deprecated and should no longer be used. Use 'android.enableAapt2 = true' to remove this warning.

It will be eliminated by the end of 2018 .. ".

Then I get another error that is

The command 'Process'' C: \ Users \ GONZALO \ AppData \ Local \ Android \ Sdk \ build-tools \ 27.0.3 \ aapt.exe '' ended with a non-zero output value of 1 ''.

And there's the problem, what should I do?

screenshots :

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For your  Error

> "AAPT2 error: check the records for details"

This issue is created when you have messed up one of your .xml files. I'll suggest you to go through them one by one and look for recent changes made. It might be caused a silly mistake.

In my case, I accidentally hardcoded a color string as #FFFFF(Bad practice, I know). As you can see it had 5 F instead of 6.

**SOLUTION**

1: What you can do is to run `assembleDebug` in your gradle console. It will find the specific line for you.

2: Adding an image for reference to run `assembleDebug.`

[image]

For your Error

> The command 'Process'' C: \ Users \ GONZALO \ AppData \ Local \ Android \ Sdk \ build-tools \ 27.0.3 \ aapt.exe '' ended with a non-zero output value of 1 ''.

First try to clean and rebuild your project from Build menu.

Step 1: go to **Build -> Clean Project**

Step 2: go to **Build -> Rebuild Project**

This should solve your problem.

Otherwise try updating Android SDK build tool from SDK manager and modify your build.gradle to use latest buildToolsVersion i.e "27.0.3" as

As i can see in your folder name its 27.0.3 only, kindly cross check with that in the gradle file... and try to change it as follows

```
android {
buildToolsVersion "27.0.+"
...
}
```